# Adding a link to a key press event

Tags: reactjs, react-router, keyevent, material-ui

I would like to add a react-router Link to a key press event in a form that I am creating. The form itself looks like this:

```
<div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" onKeyPress={e => this._handleKeyPress(e)}>
    <Paper style={styles.form}>
        <form role="form">
            <div className="text-center">
                <h2>Enter Your Details to Login</h2>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <TextField
                        hintText="Email"
                        floatingLabelText="Email"
                        type="email"
                        errorText={this.state.email_error_text}
                        onChange={e => this.changeValue(e, 'email')}
                        onBlur={this.isDisabled} 
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <TextField
                        hintText="Password"
                        floatingLabelText="Password"
                        type="password"
                        errorText={this.state.password_error_text}
                        onChange={e => this.changeValue(e, 'password')}
                        onBlur={this.isDisabled} 
                    />
                </div>
                <FlatButton
                    containerElement={<Link to="/portal" />}
                    disabled={this.state.disabled}
                    style={{"marginTop": 50}}
                    label="Submit"
                    onClick={e => this.login(e)} 
                />
            </div>
        </form>
    </Paper>
</div>
```

As you can see I am making the material-ui button a link to the next page. However, I would also like to do something similar when the enter key is pressed to submit the form. At the moment I have this to handle the key event and the login:

```
_handleKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        if (!this.state.disabled) {
            this.login(e);
        }
    }
}

login(e) {
    createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password);
}
```

But as you can see there is no transition occurring in the key press function.

My question is how can I go about adding this to the key press event so that it will also cause a transition to the next page?

Any help would be very much appreciated, as always.

Thanks for your time

Comment: have you tried to add the router to your component context and use this.context.router.push('yourpath') ?

Comment: How would I go about doing that, I've only just really starting using react-router so I'm a little confused about what you mean by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
YourComponent.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
};


login(e) {
    createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    this.context.router.push('yourURL');
}
```

If you are using React Router 2.0.0+ and you imported browserHistory from react-router as your Router history you can use this as well

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

login(e) {
    createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password);
    browserHistory.push('yourURL');
}
```

Comment: That works great for the button press but still no love from the key press event unfortunately. It appears that the event still isn't firing at all. Do you reckon there is a problem in the way I am calling it?

Comment: hm ... the event is not firing because the div doesn't have the focus, you could try to bind it in the window on componentDidMount and unbind it using componentWillUnmount.

Comment: Are you getting any error? If you are not getting any error, it's not binded!

Comment: Got it, I was just being an idiot! Thanks for your help!